# map.find(var) isn't returning correct value

Tags: c++

Sample code is :

```
map<char* , int> map;
map["Privilege"] = 1;

char* code[]="Privilege";

val = map.find(code); // returns map.end()
val = map.find("Privilege"); // returns correct value
```

I need to find the value in the map on the basis of variable key :
`val = map.find(code);`

> It is returning `map.end()`

Please suggest something

Comment: map stores pointer address. code array has different address compare to "Privilege"  string literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use std::string instead of char *
Since you want to save the string value, not its location.
Also, I wouldn't use the name "map" for a variable (since its already used)

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<std::string, int> mymap;
mymap["Privilege"] = 1;

std::string code = "Privilege";

val = mymap.find(code);  
val = mymap.find("Privilege");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're storing character pointers in your map, not strings. `map.find` compared the two pointers and finds them not equal.

Just use a `map<string, int>` .

Comment: Alternatively, provide a `char*` comparator that uses e.g. `strcmp`.

Comment: Yes, you can do that (don't forget to implement a proper hash function), but do you really want to? Using a string is so much simpler.

Comment: No need for a hash function. Also, maybe OP doesn't need to be doing loads of dynamic allocations, which would happen when using `std::string` (modulo small string optimizations)

Comment: Oh, right, a map is not a hash in C++. Forgot that.  I still wouldn't suggest using char pointers before there's a proven performance problem with using strings.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ application do not use `char*`, use `string` instead. I mean, define map as `map<string , int> MyMap;`

By the way, `map` is not good name for variable :-)